# Kendo UI MVC DateTimePicker: Custimize Time List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI MVC DateTimePicker. By Default, the time shows as a list:

12:00AM
12:30AM
...
11:30PM
12:00PM

Is it possible to customize this list? The work schedule is for 8:00AM - 4:00PM. It makes more sense to have the list start from 8AM to 4PM.

Could not find any info/question about this.

Thanks

*** I'm using the DateTimePicker in the schedule template. It maps to model.start in the model. So, have to use a DateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

You cannot with **DateTimePicker**. However, you can have both **DatePicker** and **TimePicker** together, and restrict time range.

[Documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/timepicker/rangeselection)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("StartDate"))

@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
        .Name("StartTime")
        .Min("8:00 AM")
        .Max("4:00 PM"))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm using the DateTimePicker in the schedule template. It maps to a property in the model. So, have to use a DateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

got answer from Kendo support:

You can use the "edit" event of the Scheduler to update the options of the dateTimePickers inside the editor. Demo is at http://dojo.telerik.com/UzicU/2

```
edit: function(e) {
    e.container.find("[data-role=datetimepicker]").each(function() {
        var dtp = $(this).getKendoDateTimePicker();

        dtp.timeView.setOptions({
            min: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0),
            max: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0)
        });
    });
},
```

Hope it helps.